# Scanner not working as intended(Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner m = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Map.txt));
System.out.println(m.next());
```

say the Map.txt has the line fgdfgdfgfgfdg in it.

when i try to use it, it prints the whole line instead of one token/letter at a time. How can I read only 1 letter?

P.S - I'm aware the file has to be in a try-catch block, I ommitted that here and I also tried using FileReader instead of File, same thing happens.

Comment: Why do you think it should read one token or letter at a time the way you have it?

Answer (score 0):

m.next() takes the whole word, that is every letter until the next whitespace. You can do something like this:

```
Scanner m = new Scanner(...);
System.out.println(m.next().charAt(0));
```

Edit:
For reading one char at a time you would then store the word as a string and loop through the chars

```
Scanner m = new Scanner(...);
String word = m.next();

for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(word.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: wouldn't that print the first letter of each word?

Comment: Would only print first letter of the first word. I'll update answer.